# How do I hide an area in a template or layout if multiple regions have no content?

Tags: theming

I am able to set this up using a single check for a content in a region, but what if say 3 regions must all have content before the area is displayed?

Here's what I use in my templates when checking for a single region:

```
<?php if ($content['region-1']): ?>
<p>Region 1 Content</p>
  <?php print render($content['region-1']); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But for checking multiple regions, Something like this?

```
<?php if ($content['region-1']['region-2']['region-3']): ?>
<p>Region 1 Content</p>
  <?php print render($content['region-1']); ?>
<p>Region 2 Content</p>
  <?php print render($content['region-1']); ?>
<p>Region 3 Content</p>
  <?php print render($content['region-1']); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I tried just now & it's working --

```
<?php if ($page['footer_firstcolumn'] && $page['footer_secondcolumn']): ?>
  <div class="footer-firstcolumn">
    <?php print render($page['footer_firstcolumn']); ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So I hope if you also try like this with your code with `&&`, it will work. Something like this--

```
<?php if ($content['region-1'] && $content['region-2'] && $content['region-3']): ?>
<p>Region 1 Content</p>
  <?php print render($content['region-1']); ?>
<p>Region 2 Content</p>
  <?php print render($content['region-1']); ?>
<p>Region 3 Content</p>
  <?php print render($content['region-1']); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Otherwise you can take a look here on [this documentation](https://drupal.org/node/517696) to see how you can check whether they are occupied or not in `template.php` and pass some value with variable to tpl. Then it will be easy to put in condition just like D6.

Comment: Thanks, I should have thought of that but didn't trust my php ability. This works for me, also I appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution will work, but I think the best practice will be to make this check by preprocess 'theme_preprocess_page' and pass the result ( e.g. 'isRegionsEmpty') to the template. Then, in the template you only check one variable.